# Kubuntu 14.04 freezing on MacBook Pro 6,2, not booting ldm

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, macbook

I've reinstalled Kubuntu 14.04 multiple times to fix this, but it has not fixed this problem. I have a MacBook Pro 2010 15 inch with NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 256 MB GPU. Basically, this is what happens to make the bug appear:

1. I install Kubuntu 14.04 (manual install dual-boot Mac OS X)
2. Reboot multiple times
3. Bug appears. Shows this screen [image]

   Then stops at black screen.

I have tried booting from the earlier kernel version, and it boots to ldm, but I can't logon because the upper half of the screen is covered by a weird graphical thing. Also, the upper half of the screen is unusable because it is covered in something. Is there something I should do on reinstall or something I should do to fix the current bug?

Comment: Please provide details on how you installed the bootloader, what the error is you see on bootup (maybe stored in wherever Kubuntu is configured to forward kmsg), and if possible a screen dump of the graphical defect. I have installed Linux on a MacBook Pro 6,2. it is quite possible.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu with swap root and home partitions. No separate boot partitions of any kind though I had tried those to fix the problem as well and they had failed. I've installed other Ubuntu distress like the normal unity Ubuntu and gnome Ubuntu as well and they worked fine. I'll post the graphical effect soon. By error I mean that lDM will not boot at at all. Instead, kubuntu just boots to black and freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a .img file and not an .iso file.

Look at this if it helps: [Install Linux on a MacBook Pro](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Comment: I installed it using an iso. I did it correctly using unetbootin

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the installation that is the problem. I've installed other distribution like Ubuntu gnome am the same way and they worked fine

Comment: could you provide the exact hardware you have and model of your macbook , Is it an Air, What gfx card it has etc? On Wikipedia can only find the MacBook 6,1.

Comment: @tomodachi added more info

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching your GFX driver.

First check what driver you are using. The nvidia GT330M is supported both by the NVIDIA driver and the open Source one Nouveau)

Select recovery mode from grub and drop to a root shell.

type:

```
lsmod |egrep 'nouveau|nvidia'
```

in the terminal to check which one is in use.

The steps [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) give a pretty good description on how to install an alternative driver

Comment: I apologize, but I stopped using Kubuntu after I didn't find a solution. So this question is no longer useful to me. Would you suggest deleting the question then?